# generating compilation error with pythagorean tripple application trippled nested forloop

Tags: java, pythagorean

Here is my code:

```
     //a java application prints out all values of pythagorean triples     that        range from 1 to 500. 
      //uses a trippled nested for loop
    public class pythagoreantriples{

        //main method executes java application

        public static void main(String args[]){

       //declare variables


    for(int side_1=3;  side_1 <=500;  side_1++){

       for(int side_2=4; side_2 <=500; side_2++){

            for(int hypo=5; hypo <=500; hypo++){



                Math.pow(hypo,2)=Math.pow(side_1,2)+Math.pow(side_2,2);

                System.out.printf("n/%d/n",     Math.pow(side_1,2),"                 ", Math.pow(side_2,2),"                     ", Math.pow(hypo,2));



    } //end first for loop

    }//end second for loop

    } //end third for loop

    }//end main

    }//end class
```

Here is the error that is generated when I attempt to compile my code:

```
>C:\Users\Courtney\Desktop\chapter five exercises for      >java\pythagoreantriples.java:17: error: unexpected type
            hypo*hypo=side_1*side_1+side_2*side_2;
                ^
  >required: variable
>found:    value
>C:\Users\Courtney\Desktop\chapter five exercises for 

>java\pythagoreantriples.java:19: error: unexpected type




  >Math.pow(hypo,2)=Math.pow(side_1,2)+Math.pow(side_2,2);
                ^
  >required: variable
  >found:    value
  >2 errors

  >Tool completed with exit code 1
```

What am I doing wrong? It is supposed to print out a table of pythagorean triplets that range from 1 to 500. The first pythagorean triplet that the forloop should print out of course is 3^2+4^2=5^2

Comment: The left-hand-side expression on an assignment cannot be other than an expression. You should change it to a variable and probably use `Math.sqrt` too.

Comment: What would it mean to assign a value to the *returned* value of a method? Assignments in computing aren't the equivalent of equations in Maths.

Comment: please check out the basics of programming. the `=` is an assignment operator in programming and not an equality sign in equation.

Answer (score 0):

You should change the failing statement to a conditional expression, replacing the `=` with `==`, and use it in an if-statement, to decide whether to print the current triple:

```
if (Math.pow(hypo, 2) == Math.pow(side_1, 2) + Math.pow(side_2, 2))
```

You also need to work on your printout. The result of Math.pow is a double, not an int. In any case, you should probably be printing the sides, not the squares.

Comment: Your suggestion sort of worked . when I changed the range from 1 to 200 it starts out with the 3-4-5 pythagorean triplet but when I changed the range from 1 to 500 , it starts out with the 208-105-233 pythagorean triplet instead of the 3-4-5 triplet but I am almost sure the program lists the initial pythagorean triplet but when the program stops executing, it doesn't lists it... strange.

Comment: When I tested it with a corrected version of your format and output variables, the first line was "3                 4                     5
" and the last line was "483                 44                     485
". Clearly, your compilation error, the subject of this question, is fixed. I suggest trying to debug your program's functional problems, and if you cannot post a new question about that.